Samadhi and pragya without sila
I am practicing Vipassana meditation and I want to know is it possible to practice samadhi/anapana and pragya/Vipassana without following Sila.

In Buddhism, it is impossible to develop samadhi and vipassana without sila.

If a bhikkhu should wish: ‘May I become one to obtain at will, without trouble or difficulty, the four jhānas that constitute the higher mind and provide a pleasant abiding here and now,’ let him fulfil the precepts…
If a bhikkhu should wish: ‘May I, by realising for myself with direct knowledge, here and now enter upon and abide in the deliverance of mind and deliverance by wisdom that are taintless with the destruction of the taints,’ let him fulfil the precepts...
MN 6

In Buddhism, sila is the cause of samadhi & vipassana.

In one of right view, right resolve comes into being. In one of right resolve, right speech comes into being. In one of right speech, right action... In one of right action, right livelihood... In one of right livelihood, right effort... In one of right effort, right mindfulness... In one of right mindfulness, right concentration... In one of right concentration, right knowledge [vipassana]... In one of right knowledge, right release comes into being.
MN 117


what about army? Should we abolish them. What about many enlightened person with multiple wives ? What about telling lies in order to save someone's life  ?  What about downloading movies / books from internet ?
